# jpa call procedure db2

Tags: jpa, db2, procedure

Hey guys I have a procedure in **DB2** and I'm trying call it using jpa hibernate, but I'm getting error.

Dependency maven is:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
      <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
      <version>10.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Jpa

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("GL.GLMAPOUT");
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("O_ERROR", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.execute();

gc1glcostctrmaps = (List<ProdureDto>) storedProcedure.getResultList();
```

output :

```
Hibernate: 
    {call GL.GLMAPOUT(?)}
2018-07-22 15:30:21.397  WARN 13916 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -4472, SQLState: null
2018-07-22 15:30:21.414 ERROR 13916 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [jcc][10453][12710][3.68.61] Cannot get the describe information for the calling stored procedure with name GLMAPOUT and path ' SYSIBM , SYSFUN , SYSPROC , GLDEV ' ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
```

but in the **Data Studio** it is OK

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnl6n.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your Db2 server is running on Z/OS, then you need to upgrade your Db2 jdbc driver from its current V10.5.0.4 level (jdbc 3.0 driver version 3.68.61) to a higher version to address a known bug.

It appears this bug was fixed in driver versions 3.69.24 and higher.

Download the latest fixpack for your Db2 client from this [site](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866).

Comment: To try the fix, The driver version has to be at least 3.69.24 or higher

Comment: how to i do ? with maven please

Comment: The IBM jdbc drivers for Db2 are proprietary. When connecting to Z/OS or i-Series you have to have a license.  You can create your own maven repository and store the drivers there (after downloading from the link in the answer), then reference this from your pom.xml. This might already exist inside your company. Get some education for all the details or use google.

Comment: thanks, but the error is remained in calling stored procedure

Comment: What is the new driver version reported in the Error message?